# Ubuntu 13.1 wifi authentication didn't do anything

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, realtek

Just install Ubuntu 13.10 on my second PC to try a Linux OS. I'm working as developer on windows based platforms but I'm completely fresh in Linux/Ubuntu.

When I try to connect to WiFi (WiFi adapter seems to work properly- I can see the networks), **I enter the password (I'm using WPA2-PSK) hit 'connect' but after couple of seconds I receive the authentication dialog again** (I double checked the password- It's correct).
It's seems that the network adapter can't authenticate the connection with the router although the password is right.

My Network adapter: Realtek RTL8187SE Wireless Lan Controller.

As offered in several others answers, I tried to remove and forget the network that I trying to connect, restart the system and connect again. **But it didn't help.**

Thanks!

Comment: If this is your own home network, try temporarily removing authentication and connecting. Just to make sure that the problem is in authenticating and not more general. Just to clarify, I am not recommending you _leave_ it unlocked.

Comment: Have you checked under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` whether the said profile(s) are listed?? If so, try removing from there and restart the network manager, then check. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advises, but it didn't work..
I tried to disable the network authentication and to check the folder but no success.
LAST UPDATE: I managed to connect to my phone hotspot (with WPA2 security). I think that my router have anything to do with this problem.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
<http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Comment: I ran the script and the result is pasted here [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4akm50qg).
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do `sudo modprobe -rv r8187se` `sudo modprobe -rv r8180` then `sudo modprobe -v r8187se` will it connect now? the information you posted shows the channel on 19 but you can not use that channel, try 1 or 11 and just wpa2 AES (CCMP) encryption, if it does not connect post a new file from the script and do not reboot yet. Did you install a driver manually?

Comment: Thank you very much @WildMan ! The channel switching correct the connection!!